# Voltage reference drift in ppm/°C to V/°C

Tags: voltage-reference, temperature-drift

How does one convert drift in ppm/°C to V/°C?
Assume a 5 V voltage reference has an output voltage drift of 12 ppm/°C.
What is the output voltage drift in volts for a target temperature of 85°C?

Comment: 60 micro-volts per degree C

Comment: "ppm" means millionth of the full value

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how they specify it. Link to datasheet please.

1 ppm of 5 V is 5 μV.

If your base temperature in the datasheet is 25 °C then (85°C-25°C) × 12 ppm/°C × 5 V = 3600 μV = 3.6 mV.